# Erdos use of amphetamines to stimulate his creativity

Tags: mathematics-social-history

What was the dosage of amphetamines that Erdos was taking?  Was it a constant dose or did it increase over time?  Had he ever been diagnosed as suffering from ADD?

Comment: Do you have any source attesting this use ?

Comment: Several.  It was widely known in the mathematical community.  One of his colleagues was concerned that he was addicted and bet him that he couldn't survive for a month without them.  He said that he easily won that bet, but for that month he was completely useless to do mathematics.

Comment: Page 8 of [this doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20220725011340/https://www.untruth.org/~josh/math/Paul%20Erd%F6s%20bio-rev2.pdf) says: In 1979 Graham bet Erdős $500 that he couldn't stop taking amphetamines for a month. Erdős accepted, and went cold turkey for a complete month. Erdős's comment at the end of the month was "You've showed me I'm not an addict. But I didn't get any work done. I'd get up in the morning and stare at a blank piece of paper. I'd have no ideas, just like an ordinary person. You've set mathematics back a month." He then immediately started taking amphetamines again.